# Looping through a limited number of elements inside an array

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an array of users, how can I make a limited number of iterations using twig.

I have 5 elements inside the array, and i only need to loop through 4 of them.

instead of doing like this:

```
 for user in users 
     user 
 endfor
```

it would be something like this

```
 for ... in 0..3 
      user 
 endfor
```

Comment: looks like you want to use slice. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html ({% for user in users|slice(0, 10) %})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the slice filter

```
{% for user in users|slice(0,4) %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

You can even use the twig shortcut

```
{% for user in users[0:4] %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot vincent

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twig extension [Slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html)

In example :

```
{% for user in users|slice(0, -1) %} 
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

`slice(0, -1)` means you start from 0 and end to *last element - 1*